# Why this switch statement isn't work perfectly?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

```js
const number = prompt("Enter your number");
const txt = "You result is : ";

switch (number) {
  case (number >= 80 && number <= 100):
    document.write(`${txt} A+`);
    break;
  case (number >= 70 && number <= 80):
    document.write(`${txt} A gread`);
    break;
  case (number >= 60 && number <= 70):
    document.write(`${txt} B gread`);
    break;
  case (number >= 50 && number <= 60):
    document.write(`${txt} C gread`);
    break;
  case (number >= 33 && number <= 50):
    document.write(`${txt} D gread`);
    break;
  case (number >= 0 && number <= 33):
    document.write(`${txt}  Field !`);
    break;
  case (number > 100 || number < 0):
    document.write(`It's not a valid number. Please input any valid number.`);
    break;
  default:
    document.write(`Not input any number. Please input any number .`);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Define "Not working perfectly" please. What output are you gettting compared to what you are expecting?

Comment: @HPringles it seems to always output `"Not input any number. Please input any number"`

Comment: I don't think a switch statement should be used here. Consider using if/else instead?

Comment: I want to make it with switch statement. I can do it with if/else statement

Comment: You [can't] shouldn't use a switch statement this way, each case should be a single *value* which `number` will be compared against, not a comparison itself. This should definitely be an if/else. Also you have overlap in your cases :/

Comment: @pilchard it could work. It's just terrible: `switch(true) { case 1 < 2: break; }` for example. You can use expressions for cases. However, as mentioned, it's terrible.

Comment: @pilchard perhaps I didn't emphasise enough how terrible this kind of `switch` is. I would wholeheartedly recommend *not* doing it that way and using `if`/`else`.

Comment: Really. I can't use a switch statement this way?

Comment: Sadly not no. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: @VLAZ How it could be work?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: Thanks. For your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a switch-statement, you evaluate the expression right after `switch`. In your case that would be `number`.

So, your cases are evaluated with the number. This is what will happen:

- Suppose, we enter '88' in the prompt.
- The first thing you are evaluating `number` against is `(number >= 80 && number <= 100)`. The result of the latter is `true`.
- now the value of `number`, `88` is compared to `true`, like this: `88===true`.
- this results in a `false`, so the next case is evaluated.
- the same happens for the following cases, right until the point you hit the default-case.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Comment: No problem. Remember you can mark an answer as a solution to your problem. That allows other people to find a solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why this code will not work:

- The first reason is because the [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) method return a string as you can see by typing

  ```
    console.log('Type of number:', typeof number);
    // Expected output: Type of number: string
  ```

  You can resolve this by parsing the output of the prompt method as follows

  ```
    const number = parseInt(prompt("Enter your number"));
  ```
- The second reason is because in a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement, the evaluated value of the switch expression is compared the the evaluated values of the cases.

  It means that the value of `number` (number) is compared to the expression `(number >= 80 && number <= 100)` (comparison expression) and so on with the others.

  So unless one of yoru case expression yield a number the `switch` will try to evaluate the value of `number` to the expression (which is always true) meaning that the `switch` is comparing `45 === true`, not matching any of the cases.

Just use `if`/`else` instead:

```
if (number >= 80 && number <= 100)
    document.write(`${txt} A+`);
else if (number >= 70 && number <= 80)
    document.write(`${txt} A gread`);
else if (number >= 60 && number <= 70)
    document.write(`${txt} B gread`);
else if (number >= 50 && number <= 60)
    document.write(`${txt} C gread`);
else if (number >= 33 && number <= 50)
    document.write(`${txt} D gread`);
else if (number >= 0 && number <= 33)
    document.write(`${txt}  Field !`);
else if (number > 100 || number < 0)
    document.write(`It's not a valid number. Please input any valid number.`);
else
    document.write(`Not input any number. Please input any number .`);
```

Comment: Thanks. For your informative answer.

Comment: Glad to help, if my answer has resolved your problem mark it as the solution pls